Equation to fit the reverse breakdown I-V curve
I have some I-V curves of solar cells that i want to fit them, for this purpose, I used a software called 2/3 Diode fit. This software performs fitting only for forward bias and only for positive values. It is not able to fit the I-V curve for reverse breakdown. My question is, is there any equation that can be used to fit these curves?
Best regards
